# Parsing the resuled List of Tuples using Psycopg 2 with Python3

Tags: python, list, parsing, psycopg2

How do I remove from each index of the result using `Psycopg 2` in `Python 3`?

The Below is a result of the query — Which to my understanding is a **List of Tuples**, according to [fetchall()](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html).

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost", database="mydb_name", user="postgres", password="mydb_pwd);

# Activate connection cursor
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(
    """
    SELECT
        (dmp).path[1],
        degrees(
            ST_Azimuth(
                (dmp).geom,
                ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(391139.27, 5821816.69, 1.6), 25833)
            )
        ) AS azm 
    FROM 
    (SELECT ST_DumpPoints(geometry) AS dmp
     FROM surface_geometry
     Where cityobject_id=95) q
    """)
BuildingsAzimuth = cur.fetchall()
```

Below is the short view of the result.

```
[(1, 218.030625163645),
 (1, 218.002520152173),
 (1, 218.002523848173),
 (1, 218.030628886541),
 (1, 218.030625163645),
 (1, 218.043760742269),
 (1, 218.030625163645),
 (1, 218.030628886541),
         .
         .
         .
 (1, 218.439989653911),
 (1, 218.002523848173),
 (1, 218.002520152173)]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How you are showing it now, the datatype is a nested list (List of lists). Are you sure that you provide us with the correct data?

Comment: I have re-edited the result. There was a mistake.

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions in combination with unpacking the tuple is the way to go here: First assign your result to a variable (In this case I assigned it to result_list), then use a list comprehension that iterates over the two-element (Index and value) tuples in your list, and return only the value of the result, not the index.

```
cleaned_result = [value for index, value in results_list] #Creates a new list with values you are interested in, without the indices.  
print(cleaned_result[0:3])
```

Results in:

```
[218.030625163645, 218.002520152173, 218.002523848173]
```

Comment: so would it be right to do like this?
`cleaned_result = [value for index, value in BuildingsAzimuth]
cleaned_result`
 and the result is as follows:
`[218.030625163645,
 218.002520152173,
 218.002523848173,
 218.030628886541,
 218.030625163645,
 218.043760742269]`

Comment: Definitely, If you only need the values, not the indices from your cursor.fetchall() call this is the way to go. I would say go ahead and try it out =)

Comment: And if there some result in something like this `[(391139.27,)]`.  This is list right? and how can I remove `()` and comma `,` from it? I tried with `list(the_result)`. It gave the same thing again.

Comment: If that is how your result looks, you can use another list-comprehension again to extract the value you need. Is the data your cursor returns homogeneous? (So is the format always a list of tuples [(index, value)]?  [(391139.27,)] is a list with a tuple, with only one value. Are you sure the comma is in the right place, and that it isn't supposed to be a single-value tuple like this? [(391139.27),] To extract this value, you need another list comprehension. Casting list(the_result) makes no sense because the_result is already a list (of tuples)

Comment: Yea, This is the result of,  
`cur.execute("""SELECT (ST_x(StandPoint)) As X FROM (
    SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(391139.27, 5821816.69, 1.6), 25833) AS StandPoint) as foo""")
standpoint = cur.fetchall()`
Maybe because I am extracting only the x-coordinate from this point. But if I use this:
`cur.execute("""SELECT ST_AsText(StandPoint) As Standpoint FROM (
    SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(391139.27, 5821816.69, 1.6), 25833) AS StandPoint) as foo""")`
It gives this result :
`[('POINT Z (391139.27 5821816.69 1.6)',)]`. It is always a list of tuples i guess

Comment: It's entirely logical that 2 different SQL-queries yield 2 different result. It is always a list of tuples, tuples can be seen as "rows" of data. But we are drifting off topic here; If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Yea I would like for my every list of the tuple as one list. How do I remove unwanted text or, along with . should I use BTRIM?

Comment: So use list comprehensions, like the one I've shown you before in my answer to your original question. I cannot hold your hand any further, if you still have questions you should consider asking a new question because the comment section is not for discussing additional questions, it is for discussing stuff related to your original question.

Comment: List comprehensions aren't working in here because there are commas inside the tuple like you saw above and then there are results which are the list of tuples, but inside tuples, there are 3D coordinates of more than one surface are in the string. Plus list comprehension doesn't work on the single-value tuple.

Comment: I get your point, however the data you present to us *is* cleaned by the list comprehension I presented you, and that's what you asked for. That's why I asked you if your data is homogeneous. There are a gazillion different ways in which data can be presented, I cannot show you  for each and every one how to make it ready for analysis. Stackoverflow is for *specific* programming questions. If you want to learn how to clean your data and make it ready for analysis, I suggest you google on list comprehensions, regular expressions or data cleaning with python.

Comment: I have re-edited, yes but it doesn't change my goal... it always the same question

Comment: No, because the data is in a different format entirely. You should ask a new question

Comment: Ok. then can I delete my entire question. I never wanted to ask it in 1st place... I wish I could figure it out myself.

Comment: The problem is using `Psycopg 2` for retrieving data from PostGIS geometry. It, of course, will give me different formats. But the question remains the same how do I format this data without unnecessary stuff in it.

Comment: I understand your frustration, however stackoverflow is not meant for questions like "How do I clean data", because thats not a specific programming question. The answer to the question you're trying to ask now is "It depends" because the solution is different for every format of data you retrieve. If you want to learn how to make data ready for analysis, I suggest you browse the internet for things like Regular expressions, list comprehensions and data cleaning in python. You could for instance check out [This link](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/cleaning-data-in-python)

Comment: Thank you a lot. My data is clean — 3d data in vector form inside the database of PostgreSQL.  My question is not " How do I clean data?". The link you sent is only for data cleaning in python with pandas package. Like I said I have 3D Spatial data stored in PostgreSQL. I am only pulling it out of the database with the queries in Psycopg 2. So I just wanted a cleaned result either in the list without extra commas or parenthesis within the file. And not how I wash the data. Maybe use of wrong words from me. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your effort. Appreciated